# Changing position of image on hover of another image

Tags: html, css

I want to change the position of the image that shows while hovering in another image.
How can I do this...
here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/bulina/aGX5J/1/

```
<div id="img1">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT5ckS6M6g5q7FgL1dx0gxUFudPbBA46cHUN2JhGUajD_suIOah" onmouseover="this.src='http://motherhoodtalkradio.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/pink-daisy-motherhood-incorporated2.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT5ckS6M6g5q7FgL1dx0gxUFudPbBA46cHUN2JhGUajD_suIOah'"/>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#img1{
position:absolute;
left:20%;
bottom:50%;    
     }
```

Comment: #img1 img:hover {  /* your position here */ }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure,might be helpful to you.
If you were not animating the transitions — and given the kinds of images I've grouped as sprites, I don't know why you'd ever do that — then you'd want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#home a')
    // On mouse over, move the background on hover
   .mouseover(function() {
     $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 -54px');
   })
   // On mouse out, move the background back
   .mouseout(function() {
     $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
   })
 });
```

Now, if you are trying to animate that, then you've got bad syntax for the CSS and for the calls to "animate".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#home a')
   // On mouse over, move the background on hover
   .mouseover(function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "0 -54px"}, 500);
   })
   // On mouse out, move the background back
   .mouseout(function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "0 0"}, 500);
   })
 });
```

Again, I am doubtful that jQuery is going to be able to animate "backgroundPosition" for you, but then I don't do "animate()" very often and jQuery always manages to surprise me.

here's a page: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible with normal css.
Consider using either javascript or a CSS Framework like YAML check this page if you're interested http://www.yaml.de/